# Download excel file with Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5.4

Tags: excel, laravel, nginx, vue.js, download

I was try to create a download button in my Vue.js test file with this module:

```js
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>profile</h1>
        <button  @click="download" class="btn btn-success">download</button>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci hic labore nesciunt perspiciatis quibusdam voluptatum! A alias dolores, eligendi fugit molestiae quam quo ratione recusandae ut vel, vitae voluptates! Deserunt!</h4>

        <!--<ul v-if="posts && posts.length">-->
            <!--<li v-for="post of posts">-->
                <!--<p><strong v-text="post.title"></strong></p>-->
                <!--<p v-text="post.body"></p>-->
            <!--</li>-->
        <!--</ul>-->
    </div>

</template>
<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                posts: [],
                errors: []
            };
        },

        // Fetches posts when the component is created.
        created() {
        },

        methods: {
            /**
             * Prepare the component.
             */
            download() {
                var PUBLIC_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN = "Bearer YYY";
                var LOCAL_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN = "Bearer XXX";

                var PUBLIC_SERVER_BASE_URL = 'https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/role?file=xls';
                var LOCAL_SERVER_BASE_URL = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:82/api/v1/role?file=xls';

                var instance = axios.create({
                    baseURL: PUBLIC_SERVER_BASE_URL
//                    baseURL: LOCAL_SERVER_BASE_URL
                });

                instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = PUBLIC_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN;

                instance.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8';

                instance.get()
                    .then(response => {
                            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                            const link = document.createElement('a');
                            link.href = url;
                            link.setAttribute('download', 'file.xls');
                            document.body.appendChild(link);
                            link.click();
                        }
                    ).catch(function (error) {
                    if (error.response) {
                        console.log('error.response');
                        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                        // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                        console.log(error.response.data);
                        console.log(error.response.status);
                        console.log(error.response.headers);
                    } else if (error.request) {
                        console.log('error.request');
                        // The request was made but no response was received
                        // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
                        // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                        console.log(error.request);
                    } else {
                        console.log('else');
                        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                        console.log('Error', error.message);
                    }
                    console.log('final of catch');
                    console.log(error.config);
                });

            }
        }

    };
</script>
```

when i use it locally ,file was downloaded but when use "PUBLIC_SERVER_BASE_URL" can't get the file, however i can get excel file in "[POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/)" and when i see in chrome debugger in network tab i can see response of file but it doesn't download by browser.
[image]

Comment: why do you need the base url stuff? why can't you get it using axios.get() ?

Comment: i wrote my code with this type do you have a best suggest?